# Cygwin gives error using python

Tags: python, cygwin

I want to execute below command but cygwin gives the error.
Please help me.

```
Python makeReadingsFile.py eichstaett.net.xml   test.readings.xml

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makeReadingsFile.py", line 75, in <module>
    import argparse 
ImportError: No module named argparse
```

Comment: It is saying that in the directory you are in there is no such a file as makeReadingsFile.py

Comment: i am in a path that this file exist here. although when i test the full address in the command, this error occurs:                                                                Python makeReadingsFile.py eichstaett.net.xml   test.readings.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makeReadingsFile.py", line 75, in <module>
    import argparse
ImportError: No module named argparse

Comment: what's the output of `ls | grep .py`?

Comment: this is very long...are you sure for knowing it?! argpars not exist in this list!!

Comment: i add this './' and the error does not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, the error message

```
$ Python makeReadingsFile.py eichstaett.net.xml   test.readings.xml
Python: can't open file 'makeReadingsFile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

occurs because there's no such file where you're telling it to look for one.  Your second command looks to my eyes just like the first command:

```
Python makeReadingsFile.py eichstaett.net.xml   test.readings.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makeReadingsFile.py", line 75, in <module>
    import argparse
ImportError: No module named argparse
```

and you say that this is using the full address path, but since the given path is the same I think you must mean something like "when you change to the right directory".  Anyway, the error message here is probably due to the fact you're using Python 2.6 or before: the argparse module was only introduced in [Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).

Comment: thanks alot. this is right for address problem. i move to its directory but in my eye both meaning one. how to find and install python2.7?

Comment: @hossein torki: they're different.  By 'giving the full path' we usually mean something like `python /home/someone/programs/someprogram.py`.  You can install 2.7 either by compiling it yourself or downloading the windows installer and then adding its directory to the cygwin environment variables.  There are a number of explanations on google.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but both of them are same meaning.not important, thanks